# How do I get an iterable count on a template from a Django queryset?

Tags: django, django-templates, django-queryset

Lets say I am getting a queryset in my views using the following code.

```
topics = Topic.objects.all()[:3]
```

In my template, I am doing this:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>#</td>
        <td>Name</td>
    <tr>
{% for topic in topics %}
    <tr>
        <td>{{ topic.count }}</td>
        <td>{{ topic.name }}</td>
    <tr>
{% endfor %}
</table>
```

Basically, I want a table with 1, 2, 3 in the first column, and the names of the topics in the second column. How do I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think what you need is [`forloop.counter`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.10/ref/templates/builtins/#for):

```
{% for topic in topics %}
  <tr>
    <td>{{ forloop.counter }}</td>
    <td>{{ topic.name }}</td>
  <tr>
{% endfor %}
```